# Is every regular Alexandrov topology a partition topology?

Tags: general-topology

An [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) on a set $X$ is a topology in which arbitrary intersections of open sets are open.  Equivalently, every point has a smallest open neighborhood.

Given a partition on a set $X$, one can form the corresponding [partition topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_topology) by taking the partition as a base for the topology.

It is clear that a partition topology is an Alexandrov topology (the smallest nbhd of a point is the partition block containing the point), and is [regular](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000011).

The converse should be true:

> Every regular Alexandrov topology is a partition topology.

In particular, every finite regular space has a partition topology.

Can anybody provides a proof?

Comment: Wouldn't the proof be "use the minimal open sets as the partition basis"?  Does that work?  If not, why?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097094

Comment: If $S$ is the Sierpiński space then $S$ is Alexandroff but not a partition topology. So we cannot drop regular assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is regular and Alexandrov. If $x \in X$, let $U_x$ be the minimal open neighbourhood of $x$. As Randall says, it would be nice if we could show that the family of all $U_x$ is a partition. It is pretty clear that this family is a basis for the topology on $X$, as for any open $U$, we have that $U = \bigcup_{x \in U} U_x$. It's clear that the $U_x$ cover all of $X$, so all we need to show is that the $U_x$ are pairwise either equal or disjoint.

Equivalently, we need to show that if a pair of points in $X$ is topologically distinguishable, then they can be separated by open sets.

Indeed, suppose that $x, y \in X$ are topologically distinguishable. Without loss of generality, assume there is an open set $U$ with $x \in U$ but $y \notin U$. Then $X \setminus U$ is a closed set which contains the point $y$, but does not contain the point $x$. By regularity, we can find open sets that separate $X \setminus U$ and $x$. In particular, they separate $x$ and $y$. So we are done! $X$ must have the partition topology derived from the family $U_x$, or equivalently, from the equivalence relation of topological indistinguishability.

Comment: Nice.  Your proof also shows the more general result: [Alexandrov + $R_1$ $\implies$ partition topology], where [$R_1$ = preregular](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000134) = topologically distinguishable points can be separated by nbhds.  That's a property implied by both Hausdorff and regular.  So also [Alexandrov + Hausdorff $\implies$ partition topology].

Comment: Actually my previous comment does not say much, as Alexandrov preregular spaces are automatically regular, as seen [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=alexandrov%2Bpreregular%2B%7Eregular).

Comment: @PatrickR Alexandroff $T_1$ spaces are discrete, since for any set $A\subseteq X$ we have $A = \bigcap_{x\notin A} X\setminus\{x\}$. In fact this result is on [pi-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000267). Here the power of this argument lies with not assuming separation properties that relate to points ($T_1$, Hausdorff etc.), otherwise this is trivial.